# Redirect any access to "/index.php" to "/" in nginx

Tags: nginx

Simple question really, as in the title.

I did some googling but all I seemed to find was advice on how to rewrite every page to index.php?theurigiven, etc.

I just want a rule that will make it so that if someone accidentally goes to

```
http://www.example.com/index.php
http://www.example.com/foo/index.php
```

it'll be rewritten in their address bar as

```
http://www.example.com/
http://www.example.com/foo/
```

etc

I tried a few simple regexps but they didn't seem to be working, so I slimmed it down to the bare-bones of

```
location /index.php {
    return 301 /;
}
```

And even that doesn't seem to work?

I'm guessing it's because internally nginx is silently re-routing "/" to "/index.php" (or whatever I've specified in my "index" directive, so that those files can be passed over to my php handler, via the "if my page ends in .php and the file exists, send it to PHP" block...?

Comment: You know that `index.html` is not `index.php` right?

Comment: I do, sorry.  I wrote "index.php" as that's what most people use as their index page, but I'm naievely using index.html in a vain attempt to "cloak" php from my users.  So I just got mixed up in my question, I'll edit it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much faffing, I think I've come to the conclusion that this isn't *nicely* doable in nginx directives.  It *is* doable, but only by using if statements, which everything says to avoid if possible.

So I might go down a PHP route instead:

```
if (substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],-9)=='index.php') {
    Header ('Location: '.substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],0,-9),true,301);
    exit();
}
```

simple..?